# What does getBackground() returns in android?

Tags: java, android

I have some buttons in the pp that I am creating.
I want to check if the button has particular background image on it or not.
want to know what does getBackground() do??

Comment: Here are the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBackground()), assuming this is the one you are talking about.

Comment: 1. What `getBackground()`? On what object? 2. read the documentation 3. look at the source code of the method method (your IDE will happily show you)

Comment: It returns a Drawable. Thanks any of the above answers didnt work.

Comment: *"I want to check if the button has particular background image on it or not."* Given your app. must have **set the image,** this seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 0):

`getBackground()` return `Drawable`

You can compare with existing drawable using.

```
 assertThat(shadowOf((BitmapDrawable)view.getBackground()).getCreatedFromResId()).isEqualTo(R.drawable.an_image);
```